# How to get the primary key from an external id to reference as foreign key?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

So I have a family entity class like this:

```
@Entity
public class Family {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "familyName")
    private String familyName;
    @Column(name = "externalID")
    private String externalID;

    public Family(String familyName) {
        this.familyName = familyName;
        this.externalID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

Where I will be getting only family name from `FamilyDTO` and will be generating the `id` for internal purposes and for database PK and an `externalID` to give back to the client.

Now I have a person class:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    private Integer familyID;    // should be a foreign key to the family primary key id

    public Project(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I will be taking `name` and `familyExternalID` from `PersonDTO`:

```
public class PersonDTO {
    private String name;
    private Integer familyExternalID;
}
```

Now the thing is I have to use family id as the foreign key and not the familyexternalID (in the person table), So how to map familyExternalID to family id in the family table and then add family id as the foreign key?

Comment: Why are you using `externalId` separate from just `id`?

Comment: For security purposes, dont want to expose the the internal id to the client.

Comment: So client will only be having the external id.

Comment: You're adding a lot of complexity for no observable value. If the "external ID" is equivalent (directly mappable to) the "internal ID", there's no value in using it unless you're encoding additional sensitive information in the internal ID (which you aren't). You need to clearly identify the specific threats you think you want to mitigate before spending complexity points trying to "fix" them.

Comment: I mean its important to have an external id. Can you help me with the question please?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should create a relationship between Family and Person entities:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "familyID")
    private Family family;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // getters/setters...

    public String getFamilyExternalID() {
        if (null != this.family) {
            return this.family.getExternalID();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As for PersonDTO, you'd be able to use family externalID when you build the DTO:

```
PersonDTO personDTO = new PersonDTO();
personDTO.setName(person.getName());
personDTO.setFamilyExternalID(person.getFamilyExternalID());
```

Comment: I was talking about a `requestPersonDTO` I will be taking `name` and `familyexternalID` in the DTO and will be creating a person from it.

Comment: Then you should have method in your FamilyDAO or `FamilyRepository extends JpaRepository<Family, Integer>`to find the Family instance by the `externalID` and set this instance (or at least familyID) in your Person entity,

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your answer to show how exactly I can do that?
Also when I will be putting @JOINCOLUMN ANNOTATION,  do i need to change something in my family class as well?

Comment: Regarding `@JoinColumn` annotation - only if you'd want to have bidirectional relationship between these two entities (so that the family be aware of all related family members), you'll need to update Family entity too to have @OneToMany annotation on its side as described [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Then you should have method in your FamilyDAO or FamilyRepository extends JpaRepository<Family, Integer>to find the Family instance by the externalID and set this instance (or at least familyID) in your Person entity---> should I call this method from my mapper class, would it be a good idea to call database from a mapper class? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: What do you mean by `mapper class`?